# Finding two numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that someone asked you to find two numbers in the following puzzle:

The larger of two numbers is 16 more than twice the smaller. The difference between 1/4 of the larger number and 1/2 of the smaller number is 2. What would be your response?

I'm pretty sure the answers cannot be obtained and that this is a false problem.

Or am I doing this wrong? Can you solve this?

Comment: $$y=16+2x\\\frac 14y-\frac 12x=2$$ This problem has no solution (if these equations are correct) because the two lines are parallel with no common points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As abiessu says, you have $$y=16+2x\\\frac 14y-\frac 12x=2$$

You can rewrite these to $$y-2x =16\\\  y- 2x=8$$  and as you say these cannot give a solution simultaneously.